# Smooth velocity based movement with predictable duration

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

Anyone has a good algorithm for how to get a smooth but predictable movement from point `a -> b` in 2D in any language?

I need to have one function setting the velocity each frame:

```
function GetVel(current_pos : Vector2, dest_pos : Vector2, current_vel : Vector2)
{
 var new_vel : Vector2d;
 .......
 return new_vel;
}
```

and a corresponding:

```
function GetDestTime(current_pos : Vector2, dest_pos : Vector2, current_vel : Vector2 )
{
 var duration : float;
 .......
 return duration;
}
```

Simply using acceleration leads up to lots of sliding so some good smoothDamp algorithm that can be predicted the exact dest time is what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to take duration time as an argument of GetVal? If so, you can write a function to move the point with a quadratic velocity function, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume v(0) = 0 and v(T) = 0 and, v(t) is a quadratic function which the maximum value at t = T/2.

Accordingly, we can assume the form,

[image]

Since the point moves L within T seconds, integrating v(t) from 0 to T must give L. So, we can get another equation,

[image]

Solving these equations gives,

[image]

[image]

Using these a and b, you can compute the current velocity.

It is rather long, but I made a Java toy to realize this. Please check it!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MovePoint extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new MovePoint());
        thread.start();
    }

    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public MovePoint() {
        super();
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Move Point");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Point V;
    private Point S = new Point(50, 50);
    private Point E = new Point(450, 450);
    private double duration = 5.0;
    private double dt = 0.03;
    private Image buffer;
    private Graphics gBuf;

    public void run() {
        double t = 0.0;
        V = S.copy();
        while (t < duration) {
            V = Point.add(V, calcVelocity(V, S, E, t, duration).scale(dt));
            t += dt;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (gBuf == null) {
            buffer = createImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            gBuf = buffer.getGraphics();
        }
        gBuf.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        gBuf.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        gBuf.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        gBuf.fillOval((int)(V.x - 5), (int)(V.y - 5), 11, 11);
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public Point calcVelocity(Point current, Point start, Point goal, double t, double T) {
        double L = Point.distance(start, goal);
        double a = -6.0 / (T * T * T);
        double b =  3.0 / (2.0 * T);

        double s = (t - 0.5 * T);
        double v = a * s * s + b;
        return Point.subtract(goal, start).scale(v);
    }
}

class Point {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point copy() {
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public static double distance(Point p, Point q) {
        double dx = p.x - q.x;
        double dy = p.y - q.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public static Point add(Point p, Point q) {
        return new Point(p.x + q.x, p.y + q.y);
    }

    public static Point subtract(Point p, Point q) {
        return new Point(p.x - q.x, p.y - q.y);
    }

    public Point scale(double s) {
        return new Point(x * s, y * s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's pretty much what I'm after, thanks :) But instead of having a set duration I would need to have the duration decided by a MaxMovementVelocity and the distance. Since I don't want my character to have different max speed in different situations.

Comment: @Gurran So, you mean the input parameters are max velocity and the distance that the character moves, and that the output is the duration. Is it correct? Actually, this case is easier than the above case because we have three constaraints, v(0) = 0, v(T) = 0, and v(T/2) = vmax, those are enough to determine the quadratic velocity function.